# HTML - SELECT tag's OPTION partially highlights text

Tags: jquery, html-select

When I select option and scroll horizontally for reading full content, it shows partial content, but deselecting and scrolling shows full content.

How to overcome this? Simple answers are appreciable!

**Problem sample:**

Horizontally scrolling after **selecting** option

[image]

Horizontally scrolling after **deselecting** option

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

What actually happening is members are dynamically added to HTML. I use Bootstrap and JQuery frameworks.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>


 <head>
  <title> Select - Option example </title>    
  
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div class="container">   
   <form class="row form-horizontal" id="admin_promote_members">
              
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                        <h3 style="text-align: center">Admins</h3>
                        <select class="form-control" id="admin_view_admins" size="10" style="overflow:auto;">
                            <option value="1">testing1.testing@testingtesting.comExcessTextHidesOnSelecting</option>
       <option value="1">testing2.testing@testingtesting.comExcessTextHidesOnSelecting</option>
       <option value="1">testing3.testing@testingtesting.comExcessTextHidesOnSelecting</option>
       <option value="1">testing4.testing@testingtesting.comExcessTextHidesOnSelecting</option>
       <option value="1">testing5.testing@testingtesting.comExcessTextHidesOnSelecting</option>
                        </select>
                        <div style="padding-top: 20px; text-align: center;">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="admin_admin_demote"><text> &lt;&lt; </text>Demote</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
```

**EDIT 2 (SOLUTION):** As @yuri suggested, chaning CSS to "option { display: table; } solved the problem.

Comment: can you please share your code, it's hard to understand from picture.

Comment: @Bhansa Added. But the horizontal scroll bar is not appearing.

Comment: Sorry @Naveen but i am not getting any problem or scrollbar in my browser even after executing on my system.

Comment: @Bhansa: Code re-modified. Now you can see the problem occurring.

Comment: Hmm let me see what I can do.

Comment: Try CSS `option {display: table}`

Comment: @Yuri: Not working. The text goes away the select box.

Comment: I don't see text truncated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0opxxtL9/)

Comment: @Yuri. It's working. It was not working when I added "style='display:table;'"  for each options created dynamically. I just added it in my custom CSS file. Now it's working fine. You can put this in Answer section so that I can select it as ANSWER. :)

Comment: Thanks all for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try styling your `<option>` tags with:

```
option {display: table}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0opxxtL9/)

Take a look also at `text-overflow`, `word-wrap` and those text-truncating rules